# Convert time string value to time javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this time value

```
2000-01-01T10:00:00.000Z
```

How do i convert it in javascript to only return the time

```
10:00
```

Answer (score 3):

If you strip off the training ".000Z" then you can use Moment JS:

```
var m = moment('2000-01-01T10:00:00', moment.ISO_8601);
m.format('HH:mm'); // 10:00
```

See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Answer (score 2):

You can use following.

```js
var k = new Date("2000-01-01T10:00:00.000Z");
alert(k.getUTCHours() + ":" + k.getUTCMinutes());
```

Comment: This is because your timezone is -8 hrs, and time need to convert to match your timezone.

Comment: Your example should use UTC hours/minutes to account for the fact that people live in different timezones.

Comment: Fixed, you might need to pad with 0s , if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure javascript, create `date` object with `new Date()` then use `getUTCHours()` and `getUTCMinutes()`

```
 var date = new Date("2000-01-01T10:00:00.000Z");
 var hour = date.getUTCHours()();
 var minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
 var time = hour + ":" + minutes;
```

Comment: @brianvaughn I fixed, now Im using UTC methods.